# How can I get the contents of a string before a particular character?

Tags: c#

I want to get the previous chars from a certain char in a string.
For example: myString = "26+", so I want to get 26 without +. How can I do this?

Comment: What are the different types of strings and what is your logic for getting "previous chars"?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you. I just want to get "26" from "26+"

Comment: Ok, so is that the only string you have? or do you have different types of string with different combinations of numbers and other characters that you want to pull? If, the example you gave is the only one, then Ben's answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).

```
 string str =  "26+";
 string requiredString = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('+'));
```

`strings` are immutable in C# and you have to assign the results to string `itself` or some `other` string.

Answer (score 0):

The function String.Substring will do what you need.

```
yourString.Substring(0, keepCharactersBeforeHere);
```